# Express.js with Phantom.js

Tags: node.js, seo, express, phantomjs

I'm using Greg Franko's great Backbone-Require-Boilerplate and I was thinking about SEO so I found Phantom.js

Now I'm trying to integrate it and found.
http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/

which looks like the answer but just couldn't make this work. I have PhantomJs installed.

and my server.js is

```
// DEPENDENCIES
// ============
var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    port = (process.env.PORT || 8001),
    server = module.exports = express();

// SERVER CONFIGURATION
// ====================
server.configure(function() {

  server.use(express["static"](__dirname + "/../public"));

  server.use(express.errorHandler({

    dumpExceptions: true,

    showStack: true

  }));

  server.use(server.router); 

  server.get(/(.*)/, respond);

});

// SERVER
// ======

// Start Node.js Server
var app = http.createServer(server);
app.listen(port);
```

So how would I ever plug Phantom.js in this?

Comment: phantom.js is not Node module, You have to install phantom.js separately and then run it's scripts from commandline like: phantomjs hello.js  I think you have to play with phantom.js first and then implement your SEO stuff. Check out: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Quick-Start

Comment: Yeap, I did install phantomjs, thats fine. I tried to implement the thing done in the link I gave above but just couldn't manage to make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you are looking for a node integration with express, please look at this:

https://github.com/Obvious/phantomjs

EDIT:

and here is a working phantomjs node-module:

https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
  ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
    page.open('https://stackoverflow.com/').then(function(status) {
      console.log(status);
      page.property('content').then(function(content) {
        console.log(content);
        page.close();
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```